# How correctly compare two numbers with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare two int numbers, but the functions says always that the numbers are different. I've already tried with different comparison symbols (both == and ===) without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());
  var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
  var testFailed = $('.test').css('background-color','red');
  var resultG = $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  var resultNG = $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  
 if(number1 === number2) {
   testPassed;
    resultG;
  } else {
   testFailed;
    resultNG;
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number1">10</p>
<p class="number2">10</p>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="test"></div>
<p class="result"></p>
```

And what should I do to get a "true" result if I put -10 into `$('.number1')`? 
Also if I use `Math.abs(number1)` to force it into a positive number nothing change and I get always a "false" result.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the comparison itself.

Comment: You could at least upvote [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477117/3669624), to thank people who are trying to help you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
  var testFailed = $('.test').css('background-color','red');
  var resultG = $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  var resultNG = $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
```

These are functions that you're calling and they are put in place *immediately*, the only thing being stored in the variable names are the return value. What this means is of course the background is red, it's the last thing you set it to. Of course the text is "the numbers are different!" it's the last thing you set it to.

The numbers are completely identical and if you compare them with either `==` or `===` they will return true.

Simply move your assignment code to the if statement itself.

```
    $('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());

    if(number1 === number2) {
    $('.test').css('background-color','green');
    $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
    $('.test').css('background-color','red');
    $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
})
```

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());

 if(number1 === number2) {
   $('.test').css('background-color','green');
    $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
   $('.test').css('background-color','red');
    $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number1">10</p>
<p class="number2">10</p>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="test"></div>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lines like this:

```
testPassed;
resultG;
```

Don't do anything. They just confirm a variable with that name exists (if in strict mode) and then procede on to the next line. They don't carry out some action.

Lines like this:

```
var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
```

*do* do something. They find the elements with class `test` and set their background color to green.

Since your "failed" actions are executed after your "passed" actions, it looks like the test always failed.

The solution: move the actions into your `if` statement. You can also get rid of the four extraneous variable declarations/assignments since you are not actually using the variables being created.

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());

  if (number1 === number2) {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number1">10</p>
<p class="number2">10</p>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="test"></div>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

doing this mean executing these lines. so write these line where you want them to execute

```
var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
  var testFailed = $('.test').css('background-color','red');
  var resultG = $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  var resultNG = $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
```

working code pen here [here](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/mqKGyQ)

```
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());


    if(number1 === number2) {
    var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
    var resultG = $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {

  var testFailed = $('.test').css('background-color','red');

  var resultNG = $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
}

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes. Please see below:

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());
  
 if(number1 == number2) {
     var testPassed = $('.test').css('background-color','green');
   var resultG = $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
   testFailed; 
    var testFailed = $('.test').css('background-color','red');
     var resultNG = $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number1">10</p>
<p class="number2">10</p>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="test"></div>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The condition is correctly evaluated in the `if` and `else` blocks** and the two numbers are equal.

But **the problem is** that when you write :

```
if(number1 === number2) {
    testPassed;
    resultG;
} else {
    testFailed;
    resultNG;
}
```

You are not doing anything, these are not correct statements, you are just referring to variables.

**Solution:**

Instead of assigning them to variables you will need to move these assignements to the right place in the condition blocks:

```
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());
  if (number1 === number2) {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  var number1 = parseInt($('.number1').text());
  var number2 = parseInt($('.number2').text());
  if (number1 === number2) {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('.result').html('It is the same number!');
  } else {
    $('.test').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('.result').html('The numbers are different!');
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number1">10</p>
<p class="number2">10</p>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="test"></div>
<p class="result"></p>
```